# Angular only repeats over arrays with no repeated elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, iterator

The following Angular code displays four dancing hamsters:

```
<img src="images/dancingHamster.gif" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]">
```

whereas this code displays nothing:

```
<img src="images/dancingHamster.gif" ng-repeat="i in [1,1,1,1]">
```

Here are some more arrays that work:

```
[4,3,2,1] ['a','c','b','z']
```

And here are some that display nothing:

```
[4,3,2,4] ['a','c','b','a']
```

As far as I can tell, it only works if there are no repeated elements. Why is this?

Comment: Add track by $index: ng-repeat="i in [1,1,1,1] track by $index": https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if items in array is duplicat use track by $index

```
<img src="images/dancingHamster.gif" ng-repeat="i in [1,1,1,1] track by $index">
```